# neo4j "ServiceUnavailableException:Unable to process request: Permission denied " when initialising the driver in android application

Tags: android, maven, neo4j, neo4j-driver

Both the Android emulator and smartphone can not run the application because of this exception, although I tested the connection which is well and Android can reach the neo4j database using neo4j browser on Chrome.
And this is my maven verision, test code and error message.

```
implementation 'org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.4.4'; 
Android SDK is 9.0(Pie) , 
gradel version is 3.4.2, 
and maven-gradle-plugin version is 1.5
```

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.neo4j.driver.v1.*;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Data test = new Data("bolt://holer.cc:50113", "neo4j", "12345");
        }
    }
    class Data implements AutoCloseable{
        private  Driver driver;
        private Session session;
        public Data(String uri,String user,String password){
            try {
                driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(user, password));
                session = driver.session();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
        public void close() throws Exception {
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

> org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to process request: Permission denied

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is: the Android app shutdown the Internet.
And I should add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml to make the Internet can be reached.